# Is there a way to shorten exception stacktrace when mocking objects using PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, exception, phpunit

I have about 500 unit tests, which in total have about 2000 assertions. I also have a test for a method, where there is an exception handling, which influences the return value.

I am creating the mock in the following way:

```
$mockedClass = $this
    ->getMockBuilder('\My\Class\To\Mock')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(['ThisMethodThrows'])
    ->getMock();

$mockedClass
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('ThisMethodThrows')
    ->will($this->throwException(new \Exception));
```

And that works. I pass this `$mockedClass` to the object whose behaviour I am testing, and inside this method I have logging that logs which method failed and also what the parameters were (using `print_r($parameter, true)`).

When I run this test alone, it works, but if I run the whole bundle of (500) tests, when I get to this test, the `print_r` fails, because it is no longer able to print the content of the `$mockedClass`, because the stacktrace, for some reason, is really long, and if I `print_r` the mocked object into console, the list basically goes forever.

Is this a default PHPUnit behaviour? If not, is there a problem with how I defined the mock which is supposed to throw an exception? If the code for mocking the class is correct, can I somehow shorten the output when the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPUnit's mock objects are really large when you do a `print_r` on them.  So yes this would be the default behavior.

To shorten the output don't use `print_r`.  The issue that you are seeing in this test is indicating a problem with your code.  You could have a similar object that would have a large output to your log in production.  Why do you need to log the entirety of the object?  When/if you have to go through the log to find something that went wrong, you don't want to have to scroll through lines and lines of object data looking to find what you need.  Or if the error isn't related to it, having to scroll past the wall of text generated from the `print_r`.  This should fix the problem that you are having with your assertion and make your log more useable.

***UPDATE***
Since the test works well on its own, you could try running the test in its own process and see if that takes care of it.  Add the `@runInSeparateProcess` annotation to the test.  That could reduce the size of the dump from the mock object.

https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.runInSeparateProcess

***Also:***
You need to be careful in your mocks throwing the base Exception.  PHPUnit throws its own exceptions when a test fails and your code can catch them.  This can cause your test to fail incorrectly or even worse not at all.  You should extend the `\Exception` class with your own base exceptions.

Comment: So there is really no workaround to shorten the output? As I said, if I run the test as a standalone unit, it passes, because the PHPUnit stacktrace, when the exception is thrown, is not that large, but with all the test preceeding this one (about 300), running it in a batch kills the script. You are right about logging the `print_r` representation of the object, I should probably think about it. About the exception, we actually have a base exception for our framework, but for the testing purposes, throwing the  default `\Exception` works just fine. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You could try running the test in its own process.  See the update to my answer.  Otherwise, you can't shorten the output at all.